# Converting a sharded Tesorflow Model

Tags: tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I want to use a tensorflow.js model in a react native app locally as asset. the problem is that the web optimized model uses sharded weights in multiple files. But the react native bundleResourceIO handler expects only one file. I have tried to convert the model with the tensorflowjs_converter. Unfortunately without success because I do not know exactly what the command expects for parameters. I have for example tried the following:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --weight_shard_size_bytes 60000000 --input_format tfjs_layers_model --output_format tfjs_layers_model model.json unsharded_model
```

anyone converted a model succesfully?

Comment: what is the size of the weight files ?

Comment: @edkeveked about 50MB. You're right, i forgot a zero. But it doesnt event begin to convert.

Comment: What do you mean by "But it doesnt event begin to convert" ? Doest it mean it is working now ?

Comment: What error are you actually getting?

Comment: Thx Dudes, but i found the answer. Tensorflowjs_converter is not able to convert graph model. i found the answer here:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64213104/1886202).
you can just concat the files

Answer (score 2):

the answer is found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64213104/1886202

if you have multiple sharded weight files just concat them in your console

```
cat file1.bin file2.bin file3.bin > newfile.bin
```